# Image hover hitbox not big enough

Tags: css

I’m trying to make an hover effect with an image that increase the size but it doesn’t react everywhere. For other words, how do increase the Hitbox for a image without it actually expanding

Ok, first of all. I tried to use different kinds of scaling, margin, padding, etc. but I just don’t have enough experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the width and height of the image by doing this into your `css` file :

```
your class / attriute{
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   transition: transform .2s; /* Simple animation */
}
```

And then you can add this property :

```
your class / attriute:hover{
    transform:scale(2.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to enlarge the hit-hover area of an element.

---

**Option 1:** large transparent border

```css
img {
   border: 50px solid transparent;
}

img:hover {
  filter: contrast(0.3);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
```

---

**Option 2:** add the image in CSS `background: url()`

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

div:hover {
  filter: contrast(.3);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Option 3:** Target a sibling element

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.wrap div,
.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
}

.wrap div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrap div:hover + img {
   filter: contrast(.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
</div>
```